# AWS Sagemaker SKlearn entry point allow multiple script

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_inference_pipeline/Inference%20Pipeline%20with%20Scikit-learn%20and%20Linear%20Learner.ipynb) to implement a custom inference pipeline for feature preprocessing. It uses the python sklearn sdk to bring in custom preprocessing pipeline from a script. For example:

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn

script_path = 'preprocessing.py'

sklearn_preprocessor = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    role=role,
    train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```

However I can't find a way to send multiple files. The reason I need multiple files is because I have a custom class used in the sklearn pipeline needs to be imported from a custom module. Without importing,  it raises error `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'CustomClassName'` when having the custom class in the same preprocessing.py file due to the way pickle works (at least I think it's related to pickle).

Anyone know if sending multiple files is even possible?

Newbie to Sagemaker, thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a source_dir parameter which will "lift" a directory of files to the container and put it on your import path.

You're entrypoint script should be put there to and referenced from that location.

Comment: Yes. Details here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/tree/master/src/sagemaker/sklearn

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the dependencies parameter inside SKLearn. e.g.

```
sklearn_preprocessor = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    role=role,
    train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    dependencies=['script1.py', 'script2.py']
    )
```