# AWS SageMaker SKLearn entry point in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

Can I specify SageMaker estimator's entry point script to be in a subdirectory? So far, it fails for me. Here is what I want to do:

```
sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point="RandomForest/my_script.py",
    source_dir="../",
    hyperparameters={...
```

I want to do this so I don't have to break my directory structure. I have some modules, which I use in several sagemaker projects, and each project lives in its own directory:

```
my_git_repo/

  RandomForest/
    my_script.py
    my_sagemaker_notebook.ipynb

  TensorFlow/
    my_script.py
    my_other_sagemaker_notebook.ipynb

module_imported_in_both_scripts.py
```

If I try to run this, SageMaker fails because it seems to parse the name of the entry point script to make a module name out of it, and it does not do a good job:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m RandomForest/my_script --bootstrap True --case nf_2 --max_features 0.5 --min_impurity_decrease 5.323785009485933e-06 --model_name model --n_estimators 455 --oob_score True

...

/usr/bin/python3: No module named RandomForest/my_script
```

Anyone knows a way around this other than putting `my_script.py` in the `source_dir`?

[Related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314876/aws-sagemaker-sklearn-entry-point-allow-multiple-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a gap in functionality. There is some related work in https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/pull/941 which should also solve this issue, but for now, you do need to put `my_script.py` in `source_dir`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do `source_dir = my_git_repo/RandomForest` ?
Otherwise, you can also use a build functionality (such as [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/codebuild/) - but it could also be some custom code eg in Lambda or Airflow) to send your script as a compressed artifact to s3, as this is how lower level SDKs such as boto3 expect your script anyway; this type of integration is shown in the boto3 section of the [SageMaker Sklearn random forest demo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb)

Comment: if I do `source_dir = my_git_repo/RandomForest`, I lose access to `module_imported_in_both_scripts.py`, which is the main point.