# Deploy a custom pipeline using Sagemaker SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have been having a hard time to deploy my locally trained SKlearn model (pipeline with custom code + logistic model) to Sagemaker Endpoint.
My Pipeline is as follows:

[image]

All this custom code (RecodeCategorias) does is normalize and recode some categories columns into a "other" value, for some features:

```
class RecodeCategorias(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

def __init__(self, feature, categs, exclude=True):
    self.feature = feature
    self.categs = categs
    self.exclude = exclude

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

def transform(self, X, y=None):
    X[self.feature] = X[self.feature].str.lower().str.strip()
    if self.exclude is True:
        X[self.feature] = np.where(
            (X[self.feature].isin(self.categs)) & (~X[self.feature].isna()),
            "outro",
            X[self.feature],
        )
    elif self.exclude is False:
        X[self.feature] = np.where(
            (X[self.feature].isin(self.categs)) | (X[self.feature].isna()),
            X[self.feature],
            "outro",
        )
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            """PLease set exclude the categs to True (to change the categs to 'others')
            or False (to keep the categs and change the remaning to 'others')"""
        )
    return X
```

My model data is saved in an S3 bucket in a tar.gz file containing: inference.py, model.joblib and pipeline.joblib. My deploy script is:

```
modelo = SKLearnModel(
model_data='s3://'+s3_bucket+"/"+prefix+"/"+model_path,
role=role,
entry_point="inference.py",
framework_version="1.0-1",
py_version="py3",
sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
name="testesdk3",
source_dir='custom_transformers',
dependencies=['custom_transformers/recodefeat.py']
)
try:
    r = modelo.deploy(
             endpoint_name="testesdkendpoint3",
             serverless_inference_config=ServerlessInferenceConfig(
             memory_size_in_mb=4096, max_concurrency=100),
             )
    print(f"Model deploy with name: {modelo.name} and endpoint {modelo.endpoint_name}")
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Point is, I have tried :

- adding the classes definition to a file in the root of model.tar.gz and passing it to dependencies (it should get the same from the local file aswell since same files folder)
- adding to to a "custom_transformers" to a folder in same directory as inference.py and passing it to dependencies or source_dir.

Have tried solutions from [AWS Sagemaker SKlearn entry point allow multiple script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314876/aws-sagemaker-sklearn-entry-point-allow-multiple-script) , from [AWS Sagemaker SKlearn entry point allow multiple script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314876/aws-sagemaker-sklearn-entry-point-allow-multiple-script) and from https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/725
but none seems to work and always give me a

```
sagemaker_containers._errors.ClientError: Can't get attribute 'RecodeCategorias' on <module '__main__' from '/miniconda3/bin/gunicorn'>
```

How exactly should I pass my class dependencies for it to be loaded correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was only that I created my classes inside training script and not imported it from somewhere else. After setting my classes to be imported into training, following the same folder hierarchy in inference script made it work fine.